# Program for chopping overlapping image areas and filling up to a specific ratio

Tags: c++, image

I've written a little program that I need for fixing two problems in my spherical panorama images.

It does two things:

- If the image does overlap horizontally, it cuts away the overlapping pixels from the right side.
- It fills up the image vertically with black, so that it has a ratio of 2 to 1.

I'm not too experienced with C++ and I'd like to know if there's anything "strange" in the code I've written. I hope the program is not too simple but I'd just like to get things correct right from the beginning.

I'm using Visual Studio and the OpenImageIO library for reading/writing images.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <OpenImageIO/imageio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>


// Little helper to not mess around with channel offset.
struct Pixel {
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
};


// Puts the data from "data" into "buffer" in regard of width and height.
// Assuming that "data" stores 3 channels (RGB) per pixel.
void pushPixels(std::vector< std::vector<Pixel> >& buffer, const std::vector<unsigned char>& data, int width, int height) {
    for (int h = 0; h < height; ++h) {
        std::vector<Pixel> line;
        for (int w = 0; w < width; ++w) {
            Pixel p = {
                data[h * width * 3 + w * 3 + 0],
                data[h * width * 3 + w * 3 + 1],
                data[h * width * 3 + w * 3 + 2]
            };
            line.push_back(p);
        }
        buffer.push_back(line);
    }
}


// Push pixels from "pixels" into "buffer" while considering the "offset" and "length".
// Each row from "pixels" will be copied into "buffer" from "offset" to "offset + length".
// Putting the pixel channels one by one into "buffer".
void pushData(const std::vector< std::vector<Pixel> >& pixels, std::vector<unsigned char>& buffer, int offset, int length) {
    for (const std::vector<Pixel>& line : pixels) {
        for (int i = offset; i < offset + length; ++i) {
            buffer.push_back(line[i].r);
            buffer.push_back(line[i].g);
            buffer.push_back(line[i].b);
        }
    }
}


// Returning the difference on two pixels by checking each channel and summing up the absolute distance.
double pixelDifference(const Pixel& p1, const Pixel& p2) {
    double error = 0;
    error += std::abs(p1.r - p2.r);
    error += std::abs(p1.g - p2.g);
    error += std::abs(p1.b - p2.b);
    return error;
}


// Copare first column of pixels from "pixels" to the last, last - 1, last -2 ...
// When the difference between the first and the current column
// is smaller than "threshold", chop all columns from there away.
void chopOverlap(std::vector< std::vector<Pixel> >& pixels, double threshold) {
    int width = pixels[0].size();
    int height = pixels.size();
    int chopOffset = 0;
    for (int w = width - 1; w > 0; --w) {
        double error = 0;
        for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
            error += pixelDifference(pixels[h][0], pixels[h][w]);
        }
        error /= height;
        if (error < threshold) { break; }
        chopOffset++;
    }
    if ((width - chopOffset) % 2 == 1) {
        ++chopOffset;
    }
    std::cout << "chopping " << chopOffset << " from right" << std::endl;
    for (std::vector<Pixel>& line : pixels) {
        for (int i = 0; i < chopOffset; i++) {
            line.pop_back();
        }
    }
}


// Fill bottom of "pixels" with black rows until the image ration is 2 to 1.
void fill(std::vector< std::vector<Pixel> >& pixels) {
    int width = pixels[0].size();
    int height = pixels.size();
    int nFills = width / 2 - height;
    for (int i = 0; i < nFills; ++i) {
        std::vector<Pixel> line;
        for (int w = 0; w < width; ++w) {
            Pixel p = {0, 0, 0};
            line.push_back(p);
        }
        pixels.push_back(line);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string inFile(argv[1]);
    std::string outFile(argv[2]);

    std::cout << "input : " << inFile << std::endl;
    std::cout << "output: " << outFile << std::endl;

    // Read file.
    std::unique_ptr<OIIO::ImageInput> in = OIIO::ImageInput::open(inFile.c_str());
    if (!in) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }

    const OIIO::ImageSpec& inSpec = in->spec();
    const int inWidth = inSpec.width;
    const int inHeight = inSpec.height;
    const int nchannels = inSpec.nchannels;

    std::cout << "resolution " << inWidth << "x" << inHeight << std::endl;

    std::vector<unsigned char> inBuf(inWidth * inHeight * nchannels);
    in->read_image(OIIO::TypeDesc::UINT8, &inBuf[0]);
    in->close();
    
    // Create buffer to work on.
    std::vector< std::vector<Pixel> > data;
    pushPixels(data, inBuf, inWidth, inHeight);

    // Chop overlapping area.
    chopOverlap(data, 12);

    // Fill with black.
    fill(data);

    const char* filename = outFile.c_str();
    const int outWidth = data[0].size();
    const int outHeight = data.size();
    std::vector<unsigned char> outBuf;

    std::cout << "new resolution " << outWidth << "x" << outHeight << std::endl;

    // Push data.
    pushData(data, outBuf, 0, outWidth);

    // Write file.
    std::unique_ptr<OIIO::ImageOutput> out = OIIO::ImageOutput::create(filename);
    if (!out) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }

    OIIO::ImageSpec outSpec(outWidth, outHeight, nchannels, OIIO::TypeDesc::UINT8);
    out->open(filename, outSpec);
    out->write_image(OIIO::TypeDesc::UINT8, &outBuf[0]);
    out->close();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define images as `std::vector< std::vector<Pixel> >`. I strongly recommend against this: this is an inefficient storage for a rectangular array of data, with several downsides and no upsides. The biggest issue with a vector of vectors is that each line of the image is stored in a separate memory block on the heap, meaning that a memory block is allocated `height+1` times, instead of only once. Accessing a pixel requires two indexing operations instead of one, and two fetches from different locations in memory, instead of one. Using a simple `std::vector<Pixel>`, with an associated `width` value, is the recommended way of storing pixels (all well-known image manipulation libraries do it this way). Indexing, instead of `image[y][x]` becomes `image[x + y*width]`. Encapsulate this in a class and you're all set:

```cpp
class Image {
   std::vector<Pixel> data;
   int width;
   int height;
public:
   Image(int width, int height) {
      data.resize(width * height);
   }
   Pixel& at(int x, int y) {
      // we could add an assert here to ensure x and y are inside the image
      return data[x + width * y];
   }
}
```

Note that, since C++11, it is possible to write `std::vector<std::vector<Pixel>>`, the space between the two closing `>` is no longer needed. You're not stating which version of the standard you are using. I highly recommend that, since you're starting a new project, you pick the latest iteration of the standard (currently C++17), if your compiler supports it. Add an appropriate compiler flag for that.

---

The functions `pushPixels` and `pushData` push into the vector. It would be beneficial, since we know how many elements will be pushed, to `reserve` the space first. Even cleaner, in my opinion, is to resize the vector and then use indexing to assign values into it.

The function `pushPixels` indexes into `data` with the expression `h * width * 3 + w * 3 + 0`. Besides being repeated three times with a different offset (it would look simpler to compute this index once and increment it), to me this function screams for an iterator. You explicitly loop over the indices into `buffer` in the order in which values are stored in `data`. So create an iterator into data and increment it:

```cpp
void pushPixels(std::vector<std::vector<Pixel>>& buffer, const std::vector<unsigned char>& data, int width, int height) {
    assert(data.size() == width * height * 3); // it's always good to add assertions for your assumptions
    auto it = data.begin();
    buffer.reserve(buffer.size() + height); // enlarge buffer
    for (int h = 0; h < height; ++h) {
        std::vector<Pixel> line(width);
        for (int w = 0; w < width; ++w) {
            line[w] = Pixel{ it++, it++, it++ };
        }
        buffer.push_back(std::move(line)); // avoid additional copy using std::move()
    }
}
```

Finally, in regards to these two functions, their naming: it is not clear that the first copies data from the second to the first argument, and the other copies data from the first to the second argument. I recommend that you always define function arguments in the same order, for example `(input, output)`. This will reduce the surprise when reading the code. In `main`, you define your `Pixel` vector-of-vectors as `data`, then call `pushPixels(data, inBuf, ...)`. This actually copies values from `inBuf` to `data`, but you need to read the function's code to know. Later you call `pushData(data, outBuf, ...)`, which copies values from `data`, not to `data` (it's confusing because the function declaration calls its second argument "`data`").

But, if you store your image data as I recommend above, these two functions will not be necessary at all. The I/O library you use writes the data into a buffer in the same order, so no copies are necessary.

---

A possible problem in your program is that you define

```cpp
const int nchannels = inSpec.nchannels;
```

but then don't use it. You assume that your data buffer has 3 channels. The least you can do is verify that `nchannels==3`, and throw an exception if it's not. Some image files have 4 channels, in which case your output will be mangled. Some image files have 1 channel, in which case you will be reading out of bounds and possibly crash your program.

---

`std::endl` not only adds a newline to the stream, it also flushes it. So unless you need to explicitly flush your stream, don't use it. A simple `'\n'` is just as easy to write to the stream, and doesn't incur the overhead of unnecessarily flushing the stream.

Comment: Thank you much for the great review and tipps!